# How to get Account Domain and Account password for completing installation of MongoDB 4.0.2 in windows 10 (64 bit)?

Tags: windows, mongodb, installation, 64-bit

[MongoDB 4.0.2 2008R2Plus SSL(64 bit) service customisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZNJO.png)

Comment: Hi @AdhilEDarussalam I'm not an expert on installing mongodb but I would highly recommend you to read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to increase your chances of getting answers on StackOverflow

Comment: Hi @StigPerez , Thanks for your guidance